NEEDED FULL JOIN LEFT JOIN doesn't work because date
I tried to search for solution on left join but haven't found any like my problem.
I have 2 tables:



Lag
Plant
Item
Date
Fcst




1
X
A
Sep 2024
5


1
X
A
Oct 2024
200


2
X
A
Sep 2024
5


2
X
A
Oct 2024
100






Plant
Item
Date
SOH




X
A
Aug 2024
230



I want to calculate running total for Fcst and SOH. My approach:

Join Fcst to SOH table. I use Fcst as main table, because it contain the Lag.
Next step to calculate balance. I wrap it in `OVER() PARTITION BY
Sum(SOH - Fcst) OVER (
PARTITION BY FCST.LAG, FCST.PLANT, FCST.MATERIAL ORDER BY FCST.CALMONTH ASC )

Here what I tried
    SELECT 
    FCST.*
      COALESCE(SOH.SOH, 0) as SOH
      FROM FCST
      FULL JOIN SOH
    ON FCST.ITEM = SOH.ITEM AND FCST.PLAN = SOH.PLAN AND FCST.ITEM = SOH.ITEM

SQL returns null for SOH.
Result I want to get is:



Lag
Plant
Item
Date
Fcst
SOH
Balance




1
X
A
Aug 2024
0
230
230


1
X
A
Sep 2024
5
0
225


1
X
A
Oct 2024
200
0
25


2
X
A
Aug 2024
0
230
230


2
X
A
Sep 2024
5
0
225


2
X
A
Oct 2024
100
0
115



I tried left join, full join all not work coz on my SOH table missing Lag col T_T

this is what i tried @DaleK
SELECT
FCST.*
COALESCE(SOH.SOH, 0) as SOH
FROM FCST
FULL JOIN SOH
ON FCST.ITEM = SOH.ITEM AND FCST.PLAN = SOH.PLAN AND FCST.ITEM = SOH.ITEM

No, please don't add the code in a comment. Instead [edit] your question and add it there!

What is the exact data-type of your Date column?

Fcst table date format is YYYYMM. i use this to convert to date
MAKE_DATE(SUBSTRING(FCST.CALMONTH FROM -6 FOR 4), SUBSTRING(FCST.CALMONTH FROM 5 FOR 2), 01) as Date
SOH table dont contain date , i use
TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM') AS CALMONTH

Please, always, [edit] any clarifications directly into your question.

@Edlynn'sMumny I didn't ask you for the "date format" - I asked you for the data type of the column.

I hope the Date column is not a VARCHAR

With your sample data provided as :
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  fcst ( Lag,   Plant,  Item,   a_Date, Fcst ) AS
    ( Select 1, 'X', 'A', To_Date('Sep 2024', 'Mon yyyy'), 5     Union All
      Select 1, 'X', 'A', To_Date('Oct 2024', 'Mon yyyy'), 200   Union All
      Select 2, 'X', 'A', To_Date('Sep 2024', 'Mon yyyy'), 5     Union All
      Select 2, 'X', 'A', To_Date('Oct 2024', 'Mon yyyy'), 100
    ), 
  soh ( Plant,  Item,   a_Date, SOH ) AS
    ( Select 'X', 'A', To_Date('Aug 2024', 'Mon yyyy'), 230 
    ), 

... first create a cte that will collect the data from both tables and get excat number of rows to be returned with all the data needed for later running sum calculations ...
... Inner Join the data from your fcst table with unioned data from both tables and use Case expressions to manage data retrieval for a_Date and Fcst columns ...
... Use Distinct to get ridd of duplicate rows ...
  grid AS
    ( SELECT   Distinct f.Lag, f.Plant, f.Item, 
               Case When a.a_Date != f.a_Date Then a.a_Date Else f.a_Date End as a_Date, 
               Case When a.Fcst Is Null Then 0 Else f.Fcst End as Fcst, 
               a.SOH
      FROM     fcst f
      Inner Join ( Select f.Lag, f.Plant, f.Item, f.a_Date, f.Fcst, 0 as SOH  
                   From fcst f  
                  UNION ALL
                   Select 0, s.Plant, s.Item, s.a_Date, Null, s.SOH
                   From soh s
                 ) a ON( a.Item = f.Item And 
                         a.Plant = f.Plant And 
                        (a.Lag = f.Lag OR a.Lag = 0) 
                       ) 
      WHERE    f.Fcst = a.Fcst OR a.Fcst Is Null
   )

... Now you can do the Balance calculations using Sum() Over() analytic (windowed) functions ...
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT    Lag, Plant, Item, a_Date, Fcst, SOH,
          Sum(SOH) Over(Partition By Lag, Plant, Item Order By a_Date
                     Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) 
       -  Sum(Fcst) Over(Partition By Lag, Plant, Item Order By a_Date
                     Rows Between Unbounded Preceding And Current Row) as Balance
FROM     grid
ORDER BY Lag, a_Date 

/*        R e s u l t : 
lag  plant  item   a_date      fcst   soh   balance
---  -----  -----  ----------  ----  ----  --------
  1  X      A      2024-08-01     0   230       230
  1  X      A      2024-09-01     5     0       225
  1  X      A      2024-10-01   200     0        25
  2  X      A      2024-08-01     0   230       230
  2  X      A      2024-09-01     5     0       225
  2  X      A      2024-10-01   100     0       125      */

NOTE:
This was tested with Postgres (don't know which SQL dialect you are using) but the syntax is standard SQL, it should be ok.
See the fiddle here.

A bit from standard. A SELECT needs a FROM. And To_Date isn't ISO/ANSI SQL.

@jarlh Both, missing From and To_Date() function are here just to define  sample data, OP will use his actual objects and his actual data, so that part is irrelevant. The answer is in cte grid and main sql which should be standard sql sintax. Hopefuly.!

Close to. LAG is a ISO/ANSI SQL reserved word, i.e. needs to be delimited. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Yes, I didn't check it, but yes, Lag as column name should be changed. I did change OP's column named Date into a_Date for the same reason, though.
